# How do I install GNOME via Macports on my MacBook Pro running Lion?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I am trying to install Gnome through Macports on my MacBook Pro running Lion. When I install it, however, I get many error messages, as described below.

How can I successfully install this software on my MacBook Pro?

Here's what I've tried, and what went wrong:

First of all, I'm new to OS X, worked with Debian, Ubuntu Linux distributions before. I've installed macports on Mac OS X Lion. I started the daemons:

org.freedesktop.dbus-system.plist (already started)

and

org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist

After that, I open the X11 console, and manually started the X11 script for starting gnome. I do this, because I want to get the error messages it throws. When I do so, an error like this will be thrown multiple times:

> Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
>
> Window manager warning: Failed to contact configuration server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash.
>
> See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information. (Details - 1: Failed to get connection to session: Not enough memory)
>
> Feb 18 02:03:51 MacBookPro-h2o.local gnome-session[3008] : WARNING: Could not make bus activated clients aware of DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-Wq44Ln/org.x:0 environment variable: Not enough memory

I looked at http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ but do not see how I could change the current issue.

I have 4 GB Memory, 2.3 GB of them are free.
Installed also PostgreSQL

> $ cat /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> kern.sysv.shmmax=1610612736
>
> kern.sysv.shmall=393216
>
> kern.sysv.shmmin=1
>
> kern.sysv.shmmni=32
>
> kern.sysv.shmseg=8
>
> kern.maxprocperuid=512
>
> kern.maxproc=2048

Detailed info at: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40818/how-to-get-macports-going-at-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: Can you explain, in words, what you are trying to do?

Comment: This question seems to be more about a specific port or ports than about macports per se. Could you give the question a more accurate title?

Comment: I installed macport's gnome

(this will install many other ports which it depends on.
I've searched the www for this issue and can tell that this issue will also happen to other pots than just gnome.)
I want to run gnome at MAC OS X and I did all steps needed to do this.

An old how to: 
http://wnugroho.wordpress.com/2007/08/06/gnome-on-mac/

I also created **~/.xinitrc.d/99-gnome.sh** as recommended.

Comment: @Daniel
I try to run X Windows Applications (using X11) under MAC OS.

I decided to use macports gnome. One of my friends installed it at Leopard. But I'm blessed with Lion now.